# Username Password Authentication error in spring boot using Bсrypt

Tags: spring-boot

I make Spring boot app.

Login with email = `mail1@gmail.com` and password `bob`.
I have password in BD which is HASH from `bob`.
I get this error on logging:

```
this = {DaoAuthenticationProvider@10456} 
    username = "mail1@gmail.com"
    authentication = {UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@10457} "UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=mail1@gmail.com, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D7E584DE966931641FAB9DAB525EDC9E], Granted Authorities=[]]"
    ex = {JpaSystemException@10458} "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: collection was evicted; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection was evicted"
```

I'm reading the java.docs and can not understand what to do: The principal and credentials should be set with an Object that provides the respective property via its Object.toString() method. The simplest such Object to use is String.

Could you explain please?

My git: https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.2.git

Answer (score 0):

I added annotations from Lombok to @manytomany and it came to work
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude